# VMware tools Installation

Tags: virtualization

What do I have to type in the terminal to install VMware tools.  I already have it showing up as a cd in the file system.  I am new to Linux systems and operating the terminal.

Answer (score 11):

This is an example how it works in VMWare Workstation. There're minimal differences to other versions of VMWare.

1) Mount the VMWare Tools CD.

VM >> Install VMWare Tools

2) Open File Manager and go to VMWare Tools. Extract the VMWareTools-xxxx.tar.gz to a known directory.

[image]

3) Open Terminal and go to the directory of the extracted archive.

```
cd Directory/vmware-tools-distrib/
```

4) Run installation

```
sudo su -c "./vmware-install.pl"
```

5) After installation enable VMWare Tools and reboot

```
/usr/bin/vmware-user

sudo reboot
```

Comment: While this answer is quite old, it showed me what I was doing wrong. I was trying to invoke vmware-user as root, which wasn't working. Thank you.

Comment: With Elementary 6.1 I did see a segmentation fault during the install.   Seems like it still worked though after reboot.   (using VMware)

Answer (score 5):

To install the updated and open-source version of VMware tools run the following command in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Just a quick addition: open-vm-tools are now the VMware recommended way of installing tools for "modern linux systems". No feature updates will be made to the bundled tools for linux.

Comment: FYI: The install from the vmware tools cdrom seems to also be the open-vm-tools-desktop package

Answer (score 0):

sorry not at home with my elementary install ... so I cannot verify that this package is there ... you could install open-vm-tools (note it is in Ubuntu) ...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue with the error being logged as:
`RPC greeting failed: Host software version may not be compatible with the upgrader`

I found that VMware now only makes updates to `open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop` and that the tools bundled with VMware Fusion or VMware Workstation are legacy products.

That said, this is how to install them.

This will be similar to [pdunker's answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/6711/26) but more command oriented.

---

1. Mount the drive: Open **Files** and click the CD icon with the label **VMware Tools**.
2. Right click in any empty space and select **Open In > Terminal**.
3. Run the following code:

```
cp VMwareTools-*.tar.gz ~/
cd
tar -xzf VMwareTools-*.tar.gz
# this will uncompress to vmware-tools-distrib
cd vmware-tools-distrib
sudo ./vmware-install.pl
```

4. Follow the interacetive shell to make choices and your install should complete normally.